# retrieve all products and their respective attributes using getAdditionalData in magento

Tags: magento

I've been looking all over the web on how I would go about retrieving filtered products and then get their respective attributes using getAdditionalData. Here's what I do:

```
$_collectionProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' =>1))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',9)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

This works and retrieves all the filtered products. However, now I need their attributes so I am looping

```
foreach ($_collectionProduct as $products) {
      $_additional = $product->getAdditionalData();
}
```

What happens is that $_additional returns NULL.

Another scenario I have tried is the following

```
    foreach ($_collectionProduct as $_products) {
          $product= Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());
          $_additional = $product->getAdditionalData();
    }
```

This example still displays NULL. Would really appreciate if somebody would have a solution to the dilemma. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out why it wasn't working. It appears that getAdditionalData() is not really attached to a specific product. The product view is calling this function from core file. The actual function I needed to use was getAttributes().